# Sync local git repositories between EC2 instances

Tags: git, version-control

We have several EC2 instances and each of them is supposed to have a git repository.

**Before,** we were setting up a git repository on an EFS and mounting the same on all EC2 instances, but there were too many intermittent errors with it so we got rid of it.

**Currently,** as a temporary solution, we are making a local git repo on each instance with all the same files. This is not ideal, as if we want to update something we have to do it separately on each instance.

Using a git server like (GitHub, Stash, etc.) is not an option as the application has to be in an isolated environment.

**What we want is**, if someone updated a file in one of the instances (let's say it's always a fixed EC2 instance `repo001`), the changes should be automatically synced with other EC2 instances (`repo002`, `repo003` etc.), which are in the same VPC.

Can someone please share the best practices to achieve this?

I use git on a daily basis but it's mostly just `push`, `pull`, `commit` etc., so not sure what other git functionality can be used here.

Comment: Is it possible to reconcile the requirements of "the application has to be in an isolated environment" vis. "the changes should be automatically synced with other EC2 instances"?

Comment: Sorry if I am not understanding your question correctly, so I'll try to clarify a bit on these sentences. The git repositories are a part of the application, so all the EC2 instances that have a git repository are in the same isolated environment (Same VPC). (as they are part of the application). 

Please let me know if this wasn't clear.

Comment: This would be easier with a top-level controller like GitHub or Bitbucket or something.  If I'm not mistaken, I *believe* you could deploy Bitbucket to a VPC.  Otherwise, you may need to look to git hooks for a solution.

Comment: Thanks for the suggestion, I did look into hooks for this in past, seemed like a bit of a complex solution but yeah, I think we might go with that.

Comment: @alex, if you can share an example on how to make a post-commit hook that will push that commit to other instances, that'd be great.

Comment: I'm not certain about this - but you could try https://ma.ttias.be/simple-git-push-workflow-deploy-code-server/ .